# My multimeter probes are too big to measure a laptop battery

Tags: multimeter, voltage-measurement, laptop

I'm having laptop battery problems, and the hardware manual gave diagnostic instructions involving measuring the voltage in the battery. So I bought a multimeter (never used one before in my life) and had a go... but the probes are too big. The pins on the battery are tucked into little slots that the probes can't fit into.

[image]

What should I do to measure the voltage?

Comment: anything moderately conductive will do.

Comment: @PlasmaHH That's not very helpful advice for someone who's never used a multimeter before, as I said. What does that mean? Should I just wrap foil around the pins? Do I need to buy a soldering iron? Those little alligator clip things?

Comment: I find it quite helpful for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts

Comment: @JackM Have you got any paperclips? You could "adjust" them to fit onto the probes with one end pointing out. Make sure that they do not touch each other.

Comment: As @AndrewMorton said, you can use paperclips to poke down in the little slots then connect your probes to the paperclips. But **make sure the paperclips don't touch each other**.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I think paperclips might still be too big. Assuming I could get thin enough wire, how should it be attached to the probes? Can I just wrap it around, or should I use a clip?

Comment: @JackM As a quick bodge, just wrap the wire (from the paperclip or otherwise) around the probe a few times.

Comment: @JackM You can thin the end of the paperclip with a hammer and a suitable hammer-resistant surface.

Comment: The application of common sense....

Comment: Gently push a couple of sewing pins into the contact slots in the battery then touch the probes on the pins.

Comment: @SolarMike There is nothing "common sense" to somebody new about the idea that all you need to do is wrap any old bit of wire around the probes, and that doesn't risk, say, shortcircuiting and blowing up your multimeter.

Comment: @JackM the common sense is about looking at the problem and finding a SUITABLE solution - making errors along the way is part of the learning process. Starting with a cheap MM and as experience is gained then buying a better one is also part of that.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not really sure what you're saying. I did find a suitable solution - by asking. You can't just intuit this sort of thing by yourself, and the question is hard to fomulate as a google search.

Comment: @JackM I don't agree, some automatically "see" how to get round issues such as the probes being too large by thinking "how do I make them smaller. One other possibility is to find a spare connector and bring wires out to a different size connector - that avoids, neatly, most of the possibility of any shorts...

Comment: @SolarMike What you're describing is simply the state of knowing more about electronics than I do, not of being more resourceful.

Comment: @JackM or perhaps more “this is a problem, how can I get round it”...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a small piece of electrical wire, like loudspeaker cable or telephone cable? You only need about 5 cm.

Strip the isolation to reveal the copper strands inside. Take two of those strands and wrap one around each probe tip. Do not wind the last centimeter but bend it so that it's an extension to the probes. Now you have very thin probes.

Comment: Managed it using the wire from some of those twist ties you get. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Many multimeters come with fine probes, and spare probes can also be purchased separately.

[image]

Comment: Made some like this, as the job needed doing "now" and waiting for the post was too long... but good answer